# Error detected while processing vimrc: - how to take pugins in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Today I was making my custom vimrc, but it gives me this error. It is not allowing me to use any plugins. Can somebody help by telling what I am doing wrong? These lines are the error that it is showing:

```
E117: Unknown function: plug#begin
line   10:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'rbgrouleff/bclose.vim'
line   11:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'dbakker/vim-projectroot'
line   12:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
line   13:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'junegunn/fzf'
line   14:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
line   15:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'majutsushi/tagbar'
line   18:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
line   19:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
line   20:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'bling/vim-bufferline'
line   21:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
line   24:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
line   25:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
line   26:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'tpope/vim-sleuth'
line   27:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': './install.py --clangd-completer --go-completer --rust-completer --ts-completer' }
line   28:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'rdnetto/ycm-generator', { 'branch': 'stable' }
line   58:
E117: Unknown function: plug#end
line   97:
E216: No such group or event: TermOpen * set bufhidden=hide
```

Comment: Install the plug.vim before use it.

```bash
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

See the installation procedure for your operating system on https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug

Answer (score 6):

You need to install vim-plug, you can find instructions on how to do that here: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#installation

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using neovim on Ubunutu or another debian based OS, you will need to add the path for your plug.vim file (plugins directory) in the plug#begin() line.

For example, if you are using ubuntu and installed vim-plug using `sh -c 'curl -fLo "${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}"/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim'`
, then your plug.vim file may be under `~/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim`.

Therefore your plug#begin() line should look as follows:

```
call plug#begin('~/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload')
```